# How to get the array of local variables genereted by ngFor? If possible

Tags: angular, ngfor

The next code creates local variables on every `<div>`, right?

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
    <input type="checkbox" [value]="product.productKey"/>
    <label>{{product.productName}}</label>
</div>
```

if so how can i get the array of `<div>`'s?

Comment: What do you mean by array of <div>s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain your problem very well, but I guess you are looking for this:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index;">
    <input type="checkbox" [value]="product.productKey"/>
    <label>{{product.productName}}</label>
    //i is iterator, starts with 0 and increases with every iteration
</div>
```

You can then use iterator and interpolation to give each `div` or `checkbox` a unique id, for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index;" id="divNumber{{i}}">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxNumber{{i}}" [value]="product.productKey"/>
    <label>{{product.productName}}</label>
</div>
```

First `div` will have id `divNumber0` and first `checkbox` will have id `checkboxNumber0`, second will be `divNumber1` and `checkboxNumber1` etc.

You can read more about `*ngFor` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html).

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. This isnt exactly what i am looking for so i have created a new question here [link(]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521452/how-to-filter-data-with-dynamic-created-checkboxs)
Anyway, thank you for your answer. It helped me :)